# Old fantasy book series with the two main characters being a human male and a spiderling-type female character

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book, or series of books, when I was a kid, maybe 27 - 30 years ago (I am 42 now) so the books are older than that. It involves a group of people that get separated. I believe it's time travel related or alternate universes/realities are involved.

The only real detail I remember is that the lead male character has feelings for the the female spider-type creature in his party and vice versa, or they could be in a relationship; I'm not clear on that. The group is separated, which includes the lead male character’s daughter. The book chapters have us following the different groups while they are separated from each other. I cannot remember specific adventures or if they all even meet up again. The male lead characters name is Clive, is just hit me in the shower.

SOLVED. Its, The Dungeon Series by Philip Jose Farmer. Can't wait to read it again. Thanks for the suggestions everyone

Comment: My first thought with "human male and spiderling female" is the *Daughter of the Drow* series, but the rest doesn't match.

Comment: You should post an answer and then accept it, so that the next person searching for the book can find it.

Answer (score 6):

Your naming of the hero as "Clive" makes me think this might be one of the "inspired by Philip José Farmer" series [*The Dungeon*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?4199), whose main character is Clive Folliot.  It is possibly the second book [*The Dark Abyss*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?19152) (1989) by Bruce Coville which introduces the character Shriek, described as "a humanoid spider woman."

[image: Cover of "The Dungeon," by Bruce Coville. The hero, Clive Folliot is shown in a long green robe with his hand on the red-jeweled hilt of a black greatsword, standing on a rocky shelf with crashing waves in the background.]

I have to be honest; I never finished the first book, but nevertheless "Clive" reminded me of this.  He is attracted to every female he meets, so it wouldn't surprise me if there was romance between him and Shriek.

Quoting from a [Goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/60954998):

> My two favorite parts of this volume involve **Shriek, the humanoid spider woman**. The image of the assembled party climbing down Shriek's spider silk rope toward the ocean below was spectacular. The best/weirdest part was the **strange telepathic love blossoming between Clive and Shriek**.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly **CASTLE ROOGNA**

*Castle Roogna* is the third *Xanth* book by Piers Anthony, first published in 1979, which fits well with your time frame. It has a giant spider and time travel, but I don't remember any romance between the hero and the spider - but then again, it has been nearly 40 years since I read the book.

Part of the plot outline from Wikipedia:

> The character Dor, is a twelve year old magician and next in line to inherit the throne of Xanth. To teach him the skills he will need to rule the kingdom, King Trent sends him on a mission 800 years into Xanth's past to find the ancient and mysterious Zombie Master. The character Dor travels to the past via magic and the decorative wall tapestry of Castle Roogna . When in the past he inhabits the body of an adult , an invading barbarian. He is accompanied by a (not normally) giant spider named Jumper, who had accidentally been drawn into the past/tapestry with him.

[image]

Comment: Definitely no romance between them, maybe a mild bromance. :)

Comment: Thank you, that doesn't fit though. I do remember however the lead male characters name. Clive